# Building a Linux Environment in a VM for use Outside of the VM

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, gentoo

I'd like to switch from Ubuntu to a distro that doesn't hold my hand so much, so I thought Gentoo would be interesting to play with. From what I understand though, a lot of time will be spent compiling things before I can get back into a comfortable setup.

Is it possible to do all of this compilation and configuration from within a VM, and then when it's ready, be able to boot into it?

Answer (score 5):

I think you could create a Gentoo partition, mount it somewhere in the filesystem so you can access it while running Ubuntu, then `chroot` to it and do the compiling in the chrooted environment. That's basically what you do as part of the Gentoo installation anyway. (The installation disc is nothing but a minimal Gentoo LiveCD which you use to set up a working environment so you can download things.)

In fact, you don't even need the Gentoo installation disc at all, since you already have a working Linux environment. Have a look at the [alternative installation instructions](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/altinstall.xml) and scroll down to section 5, "Installing Gentoo from an existing Linux distribution."

Answer (score 1):

Gentoo is all good and fun, but I got tired with all the compiling.

A friend of mine had his laptop setup such that he could boot Windows and run Gentoo in VMware (installed on a partition), or boot Gentoo natively, so it can be done. I would recommend setting up the dual boot first, then from within Ubuntu setup VMware or something to use Gentoo, do all your setup, and then go back to native Gentoo.